# Tried running sudo apt-get update and it can't find the release files

Tags: apt, updates

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu so I'm still learning many of the features it has to offer. Today I installed OBS and a icon theme (shadow-icons) and when I run sudo apt-get update I get these errors.

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/icons/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/icons/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've looked all over the web for a solution and can't seem to find one. Only thing I could locate remotely close was commenting out

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (201708$
```

but alas this helps none and was already commented out before hand. Any help would be appreciated for a solution to this issue. Thanks!

Comment: The last update to the PPA was 144 weeks ago (almost three years) and the last supported Ubuntu version was trusty - Please review [https://launchpad.net/~kirillshkrogalev/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-next](https://launchpad.net/~kirillshkrogalev/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-next) to verify this yourself.  You should open "Software & Updates", choose the "Other Software" tab and uncheck the PPA.  The upubuntu-com PPA is slightly newer (updated 104 weeks ago) but only supports up to Wily.

Answer (score 1):

This error says that there is a problem with a software repository.  One solution that can work for you is to remove this repository from the list. This way apt-get will not look for this problematic repository.  (Unless you really need that one, but we could look into this later, if this is the case.)

The configuration files of apt-get are in:

- the text file: `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- all text files located in the dir: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

You can "soft" remove  (i.e. "comment them out") the repositories that are listed in the above files by adding `#` character at the beginning of the line where the repository is listed (just as in the example you gave about `#deb cdrom:...`).

#### Tips:

You will need a superuser privileges to complete this, and one way to elevate your privileges is e.g. `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`.  You can then browse other files in gedit's open-dialog-box,

You can easily find the file to work with by running:

```
grep -ril kirillshkrogalev /etc/apt
grep -ril upubuntu-com /etc/apt
```

Edit: Thank you [Chai T. Rex](https://askubuntu.com/users/616451/chai-t-rex) for pointing out [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/270019/616451)

Comment: [`sudo -H` or `gksudo` should be used with graphical programs like `gedit`](https://askubuntu.com/a/270019/616451).

Comment: Accessed the sources.list file and the two troublesome repositories are not in the file at all. However they are in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d dir.  So I did as you said and I accessed the text files within the dir and commented out everything I could and now apt-get update works with no errors! Thank you for your help I think I was on the right track with what I needed to do just didn't know where to look at first.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!  Great! :-) If you think that my answer was helpful to you, I would really appreciate If you could mark it as accepted, or upvote it if it was at least a little supportive to you.  All the best with Ubuntu, it is a great piece of software with a great community!